# YARN allocating containers on a particular node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

all
I am developing a Yarn application which request allocating containers on a particular node recently.
I write my code like this:

```
String[] nodes = {…};
ContainerRequest request = new ContainerRequest(capability, nodes, null, priority, false, null);
```

I have set the Relax_Locality as false, and set yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay as -1, but I still can’t get the specific container I asked for.
Can someone help me?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is an open issue in YARN (check [YARN-1412](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1412))